# Field is not showing in product.template odoo8

Tags: python, css, xml, odoo

What I am doing wrong? I have here one image here in this image heading **250g Lays Pickels** after this heading I want to show **internal reference** field. you can see in this image right side**internal reference** field.please have a look this image sample https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHKsd.png

**This is *xml file**

```
 <openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="product_template_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">product.template.form.view</field>
            <field name="model">product.template</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//div[@class='oe_title']/h1" position="after">
                    <label class="oe_edit_only" for="default_code" string="Internal reference"/>
                    <field name="default_code" class="oe_inline"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>


    </data>
</openerp>
```

**This is *python file**

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class product_template(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'product.template'
    _columns = {

        'default_code': fields.char('Internal Reference', select=True),
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code,

```xml
<record id="product_template_only_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">product.template.form.view</field>
  <field name="model">product.template</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='default_code']" position="replace"/>
    <xpath expr="//div[@class='oe_title']/h1" position="after">
      <label class="oe_edit_only" for="default_code" string="Internal Reference"/>
      <field name="default_code" class="oe_inline"/>
    </xpath>

  </field>
</record>
```

[image]

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Oh it's my mistake. Replace that `>` with double quotes. Updated my answer.

Comment: @PragyaChhabra,its div not dic and also remove > from the expression. Updated my answer.

Comment: I try many ways but  internal reference field is not showing after heading.there are only blank space.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you!  Its really so nice of you for helping you over this.
This would not have been so quick without your help.